# ASP.NET MVC gzipping doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization, gzip, yslow

After adding to my Web.config the following line of code:

```
<system.webServer>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false"/>

// other code
</system.webServer>
```

YSlow still notifies me that my plain text components should be compressed and I'm given an F mark. What could be the cause?

Comment: What web server are you using?